# Cannot add elements to array after adding one

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying out AngularJS and very new to it.

```
<html ng-app="DemoApp">
<head>
<script src="/Angular/jslibs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Angular/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/Angular/app/services/personData.js"></script>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Angular Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="userCtrl">
        <h2>Actor List:</h2>
        <hr>
        <ul ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <li>{{person.name}} in {{person.city}}
                <button ng-click="removeActor($index)">Delete</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="actor.name" /> <input
            type="text" placeholder="City" ng-model="actor.city" />
        <button ng-click="addActor()">Add</button>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var demoApp = angular.module("DemoApp", []);

demoApp.controller("userCtrl", function($scope, personData) {

    $scope.actor = personData.getActor();
    $scope.persons = personData.getPersons();
    $scope.addActor = personData.addActor;
    $scope.removeActor = personData.removeActor;

});
```

personData.js:

```
demoApp.factory("personData", function() {

    var actor = {
        name : "",
        city : ""
    };

    var persons = [ {
        name : "User1",
        city : "Location1"
    }, {
        name : "User2",
        city : "Location2"
    }, {
        name : "User3",
        city : "Location3"
    } ];

    return {

        addActor : function() {
            persons.push(actor);
            actor = {
                name : "",
                city : ""
            };
        },

        removeActor : function(index) {
            persons.splice(index, 1);
        },

        getPersons : function() {
            return persons;
        },

        getActor : function() {
            return actor;
        }

    }
});
```

My problem is that I am not able to add elements to the array after adding one. Even after setting the actor to "" , any change to the text changes the value in the array.

Comment: don't use same name everywere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.actor = personData.getActor();
$scope.addActor = personData.addActor;
```

The first statement will assign the personData object to `$scope.actor` when you call `addActor`, you push that actor to the array, and you create a new object, but `$scope.actor` is still pointing to the original actor object.

Change to:

```
$scope.addActor = function() {
    personData.addActor();
    $scope.actor = personData.getActor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  **$scope.addActor = personData.addActor();** because addActor is function 
in your controller you are not calling function.

And in controller you have to create function  $scope.addActor(); because you call **ng-click addActor()**

**Controller**:

```
$scope.addActor : funtion(){
  personData.addActor();
  $scope.persons = personData.getPersons();
}
```

Comment: can u be more specific

Comment: simply use give  function in your controller and remove  $scope.addActor = personData.addActor; this line and let me know it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

try to create a function in your controller, and pass the actor object which you want to add

```
$scope.addActor = function(){
  personData.addActor($scope.actor);
    };
```

in your service

```
addActor : function(actor) {
 persons.push(actor);
  },
```